# Wordpress caching SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

There are a lot of sql queries in my wordpress theme,
for example, 20 sql query in last 6 added posts. So, normally there are minimum 100-150 query in my website and my website is loading late because of this.

I heard about transient_api and tried to cache queries with it but I failed.

**Here is my last added posts code:**

```
<?php
    $gostermeid = $gosterme;
    $kategoriid = $kategori;
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=:-'.$gostermeid.'&posts_per_page='.$kactane.'&post_type[]=post&post_type[]=galeri&post_type[]=video&blazersix_update_post_thumbnail_cache=true' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="post">
.
.
.
```

And I tried caching them like this

```
<?php
                $gostermeid = $gosterme;
             $kategoriid = $kategori;
             if ( false === ( $catquery = get_transient( 'lastaddedcache' ) ) ) 

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=:-'.$gostermeid.'&posts_per_page='.$kactane.'&post_type[]=post&post_type[]=galeri&post_type[]=video&blazersix_update_post_thumbnail_cache=true' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
set_transient( 'lastaddedcache', $catquery, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );


            ?>
```

After this code, on the second refresh of my page, my last added posts are not showing. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix my code?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Take a look at mysql query cache, it might improve your wp site without this code based caching layer

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as I mentioned my other replies, I will sell this theme and I have to do caching in my theme files

Comment: You would not be the first one to advice database settings for their product :)

Comment: Breeze is a cache plugin that offers the most complete set of functionality for all your WordPress cache management requirements. At the time of this email, it has 20,000+ active installs and the number is rising rapidly. It provides all industry-standard functionalities, completely FOR FREE.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breeze/

Answer (score 0):

Your code **ignores changes** to the value of `$catquery` for twelve hours after you set it. That's what caching means. Your last added posts will not show.

You probably need to invalidate the cache when you add posts. That means you need to [use `delete_transient()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient) from somewhere in the code path that adds new posts.

Adding a cache to an existing data system can be difficult, because you must either tolerate stale data or find every place the cache needs to be invalidated. Caching is a foundational concept in computer engineering, partly because it's hard.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of W3 super cache or similar, and set it up to cache the database queries and objects? It will also help you by minifying assets, and caching the full site and its html.

Comment: It is possible, but I am selling this theme and I want to include caching system **without plugin** for next version.

Comment: So as O. Jones said in his answer, you need to make a call to delete the caching on adding a new post. You can do so by adding a custom hook.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

You would need to call the method to delete the cache on every new post or update to an existing post.

Comment: But I didn't add any new post in my tests and the cached posts still didn't show up. Do I have to add _delete cache code_ to see my cached posts ?

Comment: Changing the caching temporarily to a minute or two. 
Try this:
<?php
 $gostermeid = $gosterme;
 $kategoriid = $kategori;
 
 // get the cached data
 $data = get_transient('lastaddedcache');
 
 // check to see if data was successfully retrieved from the cache
 if( false === $data ) {
  $data = new WP_Query( 'cat=:-'.$gostermeid.'&posts_per_page='.$kactane.'&post_type[]=post&post_type[]=galeri&post_type[]=video&blazersix_update_post_thumbnail_cache=true' );
  set_transient( 'lastaddedcache', $data, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
 }
 while($data->have_posts()) : $data->the_post();
?>

Comment: Thanks for code, but it didn't decrease query number, still same